# Node 4.x in the IBM Node buildpack?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, iojs

Node.js 4.0, 4.1 is out, but my application is still staging with Node 0.12.x. When will either versions of io.js or Node.js be availaible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

expect a solution soon (couple of weeks, hopefully less) as some in depth testing is required to ensure compatibility with all aspects of the platform. IBM is a core member of the Node.js foundation and we are keen to keep this run time up to date.

You can always create your own cloud foundry build pack and deploy it in Bluemix should you require 4.0+ now. See the CF website for docs on how do that and the current Node.js build pace can be found here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack

Answer (score 1):

I've created a buildpack that deploys the Node.js v4 on IBM Bluemix.
https://github.com/jthomas/nodejs-v4-buildpack

You can use this when deploying your application along with the node engine parameter in your package.json to run on node v4.

Comment: There's lots more information about this here:
http://jamesthom.as/blog/2015/09/18/node-dot-js-v4-in-cloud-foundry/